# Visualize Real Time Data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, real-time, visualization, powerbi

any suggestions as to what tools I should use to visualize data aggregated into MongoDB on my desktop? I am trying to visual stock data that I've pulled from an API and would like stream said data being pulled into MongoDB in real time. Any suggestions? Is power BI a good go to? Kinda lost here...

Comment: Power BI does not (yet) have a connector for MongoDB. Go vote for it here https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7017782-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

You can use **MongoDB BI connector** with Power BI's **On-Premise Gateway** solution for Mongo DB. But, it won't give you real time data. You will have to refresh your dataset periodically.

If you want to go with real time data visualization, you should try Power BI's **Real Time Streaming** functionality with **API** or **PubNub**.